# Error installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 (x86 and amd64, both fail) on VirtualBox 14.3.26 on OSX 10.10 and I'm getting the following error:

```
[ 0.000000] Fast TSC calibration failed.]
```

Strangely, I was able to successfully install the same image on the same virtual box a half hour ago.

What's going on here?

Comment: this should just be a warning in modern kernels, not an error that stops boot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055593/how-to-solve-fast-tsc-calibration-failed-issue-that-occurs-on-boot-in-virtualbox

Comment: Right, but my error is on installation not on a regular boot :(